# Does Google Cardboard SDK work with Unity 5?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I have converted my working project from Unity  into Unity 5 and now the stereoscopic display doesnt work.

It seems like the stereoscopic effect doesnt work. The display is split in the middle, and the shader is applied, but it seems like there is only once camera. Like there are no eye cameras.

The weirdest thing is that everything works perfectly in the editor, but when I run it on device it seems like the cameras are disabled.

I went through and tried everything in the "known issues" in Cardboard SDK Release Notes, but nothing works.

Has anyone succesfully run a Cardboard game on Unity 5?

Comment: Do you mean that there is only one view of the scene and it is broken into two pieces by the dividing line?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean

Comment: I answered you here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29211684/google-cardboard-unity-5-no-stereoscopy/29222951

Comment: try running the app and checking the logs via adb. I have made a Cardboard game on Unity 5, but I had another problems - the game randomly displayed textures or lightmaps instead of the stereo cameras. Otherwise everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have done. Mine isn't big one but has major things that can be said to be using UNITY features as well. I cant predict your problem as such but Answer to this post is certainly YES.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that anyone has posted this yet, but it appears that the SDK is currently broken in Unity 5.

From: [Cardboard SDK Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/unity/release-notes)

> Unity 5 rendering issues: As of Unity build 5.0.0f4, the following steps should be taken to fix or ameliorate any rendering issues, such as an all-black screen, flashing textures, or non-stereo views:
>
> Enable the Development Build option in the Build dialog. This seems to fix various rendering glitches, like flashing textures.
>
> The root cause of the rendering glitches is under analysis, with assistance from Unity.

I have also found that the app has rendering issues when it initially runs when you hit "Build and Run". Closing the app from the task switcher and restarting seems to resolve the issue.