# Google Cardboard Unity 5 no stereoscopy

Tags: android

My Cardboard app doesn't have stereoscopic effect on device. However it works in Editor.

This is how it looks in Editor.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sN14x.png

This is how it looks on device
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XpeD.png

It has worked with Unity 4.6.

I have tried it on multiple devices.

Config:
-Unity 5.0.0f4 Personal
-Cardboard SDK v0.4.5
-tried on Galaxy Note 4 and Nexus 10

Answer (score 1):

It's spreading one eye across both halves of the screen.  The most common reason is due to rendering image effects (fog, etc).  To deal with those,
make sure the StereoController property "Direct Render" is set to false.